# Syntax error when running matlab code

Tags: matlab

I downloaded some matlab code, when trying to run a test file, it ends finding a syntax error, this one here:

```
parse error near line 151 of file /media/34GB/escola/efficientLBP/pixelwiseLBP.m
syntax error
>>>>            [minLBP, ~]=sortNeighbours( binaryWord, weigthVec,...
           ^
```

The code it is:

```
    else % if iChan==1 || isChanWiseRot
                [minLBP, ~]=sortNeighbours( binaryWord, weigthVec,...
                    iCircShiftMinLBP(iRow, iCol) );
```

What is wrong here? Thanks for the time.

P.S: EDITED

Here is the extra code requested:

```
for iRow=( filtDimsR(1)+1 ):( padImgSize(1)-filtDimsR(1) )
    for iCol=( filtDimsR(2)+1 ):( padImgSize(2)-filtDimsR(2) )
        subImg=chanImgPad(iRow+( -filtDimsR(1):filtDimsR(1) ),...
            iCol+( -filtDimsR(2):filtDimsR(2) ));
        % find differences between current pixel, and it's neighours
        diffVec=sum(sum( filtR.*repmat(subImg,[1, 1, nNeigh]) ));
        diffVec=roundnS(diffVec, nEps);
        binaryWord=( diffVec(:)>=0 );
        if isRotInv
            if iChan==1 || isChanWiseRot % go through all posible binary
                % word combination, finding minimal LBP
                [minLBP, iCircShiftMinLBP(iRow, iCol)]=...
                    sortNeighbours(binaryWord, weigthVec);
            else % if iChan==1 || isChanWiseRot
                [minLBP, ~]=sortNeighbours( binaryWord, weigthVec,...
                    iCircShiftMinLBP(iRow, iCol) );
            end % if iChan==1 || isChanWiseRot
        else
            minLBP=weigthVec*binaryWord;
        end % if isRotInv
        currChanLBP(iRow, iCol)=cast( minLBP,  outClass);   % convert to decimal.
    end % for iCol=(1+filtDimsR(2)):(imgSize(2)-filtDimsR(2))

    % Present waitbar- a bar with progress, time passed and time remaining
    waitbarTimeRemaining(hWaitbar, hTicPixelwiseLBP,...
        (( iRow-filtDimsR(1) )+nRows*(iChan-1))/(nClrChans*nRows));
end % for iRow=(1+filtDimsR(1)):(imgSize(1)-filtDimsR(1))
```

Comment: We need more code than half a line for that.

Comment: The error is probably in a line somewhere before this that failed to close parentheses or something.

Comment: True, I edited and added a lot more of code. Thanks for the effort